# PowerAutomate Get All File Paths and Names With Extension Using HTTP Request

Tags: power-automate

I'm pretty new to Power Automate, please bear with me

I need to retrieve all the Excel files' paths and names using power automate and save them to an Excel table. I've managed to partially do so with Get Files(properties only). However,this Flow here doesn't retrieve all the files, it skips many of them also, it takes too long to complete. Like 1h40m.

After doing some research, I've come across information it can also be done with an HTTP request but couldn't find any guide for that.

I'd really appreciate your assistance regarding how to start with this.

[image]

[image]